# Pairs and dict in python

Tags: python

I want to create pairs in python similar to C++. In C++, I can create pairs like-

```
(345,400)
(345,401)
(346,500)
(347,200)
using pair<int,int>
```

Is there some way I can do this in python also. Also, I want to use `dict` on this pair something like -

```
dict[(345,400)]=1
dict[(345,401)]=0
```

Can I do this is python?I am using python3.

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly as you think, it will work. The key `(x,y)` is called a **tuple** in Python and is a regular type.

From the interactive console:

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict[(1,2)] = 1
>>> dict
{(1, 2): 1}
```

List of pairs work exactly the same way :

```
>>> pairs = [(1,2), (2,3)]
>>> dict[pairs[0]] = 1
>>> dict
{(1, 2): 1}
```

Python is a really intuitive language, I advice you to always try your first idea, you will see it often works as expected :).

Comment: Ok but how can I create a list of pairs. Because I would want to use something like `dict[arr[i]] =1` where arr[i] will be (1,2) i.e a pair

Comment: @Joker Use list of tuples: arr = [(1,2), (3,4), (4,5)]

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples containing two values (as dictionary keys, also).

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of pairs or tuples:

```
  [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```